# Power bi web report display in full screen

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Is any way to display power bi reports in full screen on my website? I have read
[there](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/11718594-full-screen-mode-for-web-embedded-power-bi-visuali) that I only have to add allowfullscreen=“true” parameter to my iframe what I have already done and nothing is happend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $scope.toggleFullScreen = function () {
        var iframe = angular.element(_iframeId);
        var elem = iframe[0];
        var requestFullScreen = elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem.requestFullscreen || elem.msRequestFullscreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullscreen;
        requestFullScreen.call(elem);
    };
```

It's how i resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when i put below code..

```
var element = document.getElementById('Report'); //Report = Report containerid
var report = powerbi.get(element);
report.fullscreen();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `?rs:embed=true` to the end of the report url (if there's no query param yet, otherwise it's `&rs:embed=true`).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following javascript code for your HTML button:

```
function fullscreen() {
            
   var embedContainer = $('#report-container')[0]; // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
   var report = powerbi.get(embedContainer); // Get a reference to the embedded report
            
   report.fullscreen(); // Displays the report in full screen mode.
}
```